# How to assign condition to each element in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
aa=[1,2.5,3]
```

I want to assign condition for this list so it return based on values : "Hello", "Bonjour", "Salut".

I tried the following function:

```
def ab():
    for a in aa:
        if a<2 : return "Hello"
        if 3>a>2 : return "Salut"
        else: return "Bonjour"
```

but it only returns : `'Hello'`
How ever I want it to return : `['Hello','Salut','Bonjour']`

How to make it work ? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: your second `if` needs to be an `elif`

Comment: it still returns only 'Hello' not list ['Hello','Salut','Bonjour']

Comment: @Nina Create an empty list and append the item when the condition is met. The current way will break as soon as the first condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
result = [ "Hello" if n < 2 else "Salut" if n < 3 else "Bonjour" for n in aa]
print(result)
```

This prints:

```
['Hello', 'Salut', 'Bonjour']
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` statements in python will immediately end the function and return the value. Therefore, you need to store the values internally and return the values after you are done checking all of the elements.

For example:

```py
def ab():
    output_save = []
    for a in aa:
        if a<2 : output_save.append("Hello")
        elif 3>a>2 : output_save.append("Salut")
        else: output_save.append("Bonjour")
    return output_save
aa=[1,2.5,3]
ab()
```

returns

```py
['Hello', 'Salut', 'Bonjour']
```

### `if` vs `elif`

Learn to use `elif`! 
It can optimize your code and make it more readable.

Example:

```py
if 90 <= grade:
    print('A')
elif 80 <= grade:
    print('B')
elif 70 <= grade: 
    print('C')
elif 60 <= grade:
    print('D')
else:
    print('F')
```

is equivalent to

```py
if 90 <= grade:
    print('A')
if 80 <= grade < 90:
    print('B')
if 70 <= grade < 80:
    print('C')
if 60 <= grade < 70:
    print('D')
if grade < 60:
    print('F')
```

### Passing things in as parameters

Typically, you want to avoid the use of "global"s. If you can help it, you should pass things in as parameters (sometimes this can't be avoided, but for the most cases, you should do this).

I would rewrite the code as:

```py
def greeting_by_values(values_list):
    greeting_list = []
    for value in values_list: 
        if value < 2:
            greeting_list.append("Hello")
        elif value < 3: 
            greeting_list.append("Salut")
        else:
            greeting_list.append("Bonjour")
    return greeting_list
values=[1,2.5,3]
print(greeting_by_values(values))
```